# Android app rejection issue with Violation

Tags: app-update

We have tried publish a new version of existing app on Play store but the update got rejected With the issue :-  Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements

Also We have received an email with Title: "Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements"

And it also followed by: Apps that contain elements that appeal to children must comply with all Families Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:

Eligibility Issue :-
Webviews:
We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website, regardless of ownership, or to aggregate content that does not belong to the developer. To resolve this issue, please remove violating content and resubmit your app.

Please help me to sort out this issue

Answer (score 0):

It simply says what you should do: We don’t allow apps whose primary purpose is to provide a webview of a website, regardless of ownership, or to aggregate content that does not belong to the developer.

They cannot control the content when the webview is on the way. Therefore, they simply rejected your app for the families policy requirements. You need to explain why you use Webview or you need to remove the webview logic